# Rook-Ceph OSD pods not getting created

Tags: ceph, rook-storage, kubernetes-rook

I have a fresh cluster with a few nodes. Each node is a Linux VM with a 6GB device mounted at dev/sdc1 which I would like to use. When I try to create the rook ceph cluster, rook-ceph-osd-prepare pod logs shows that it is skipping dev/sdc1 because of “Has BlueStore device label”

The sdc1 device is created and mounted  using the following powershell commands.

```
New-VHD -Path $path -SizeBytes $size
$disk = Mount-VHD -Path $path -PassThru
Initialize-Disk $disk.DiskNumber -PartitionStyle MBR
$partition = New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize -DiskNumber $disk.DiskNumber
Dismount-VHD -Path $path
Add-VMHardDiskDrive -VM $vm -ControllerType SCSI -ControllerLocation 3 -Path $path
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common issue on Ceph. Below I am citing a *possible reason* and *possible solution* from the official documentation for [OSD pods are not created on my devices](https://github.com/rook/rook/blob/master/Documentation/ceph-common-issues.md#osd-pods-are-not-created-on-my-devices).

---

**Possible Reason**:

---

> One common case for failure is that you have re-deployed a test cluster and some state may remain from a previous deployment.
> If your cluster is larger than a few nodes, you may get lucky enough that the monitors were able to start and form quorum.

---

**Possible Solution**:

---

> If the error is from the file that already exists, this is a common problem reinitializing the Rook cluster when the local directory used for persistence has **not** been purged.
> This directory is the `dataDirHostPath` setting in the cluster CRD and is typically set to `/var/lib/rook`.
> To fix the issue you will need to delete all components of Rook and then delete the contents of `/var/lib/rook` (or the directory specified by `dataDirHostPath`) on each of the hosts in the cluster. Then when the cluster CRD is applied to start a new cluster, the rook-operator should start all the pods as expected.

Comment: The issue is this is a fresh cluster where rook has just been installed. It’s unlikely that this is the possible reason.

Comment: Removing /var/lib/rook from each node does not do any thing. Same error still remains even after fresh installation? any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format disk with `sgdisk --zap-all /dev/xxx` and delete `dataDirHostPath` of specific osd.